# Can I claim French citizenship by descent if my French father passed away in 1992?

Tags: france, citizenship

My father was a French citizen but he passed away in 1992 in India. He lived in France and passed away during his visit to India. My mom and I are still Indians as we couldn't track my dad's documents. He had French citizenship at the time of my birth. Now we have found his French passport. I am 32 years old. Can I claim for French citizenship using my dad's French passport and other relevant documents?

Comment: Did you ask the French consulate or do any other research?  What did you find?

Answer (score 4):

You should contact your nearest French consulate. Here are some indicators:

- [Wikipedia on French Nationality law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law#Through_parentage_.28right_of_blood.29)

> The child (legitimate or natural) is French if at least one parent is French.
>
> [...]
>
> Parentage to the parent from whom the French nationality is claimed, must be established while the child is still a minor (under 18).

- The french service public has a [list of required documents](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1051) to issue a certificate of French nationality (click *"Pièces à fournir"* - *"Vous êtes né à l'étranger et l'un de vos parents est français"*, in French, you guessed it):

  > - 1 photo d'identité,
  > - 1 justificatif d'identité,
  > - 1 justificatif de domicile (facture récente d'électricité, contrat de location, avis d'imposition...),
  > - 1 copie intégrale de votre acte de naissance avec indication de votre filiation,
  > - 1 copie intégrale de l'acte de naissance de chacun de vos parents,
  >     tous documents concernant vos parents justifiant de la possession d'état de Français (carte nationale d'identité, passeport, carte d'immatriculation consulaire, certificat de nationalité, livret militaire, carte d'électeur...),
  > - 1 copie intégrale de l'acte de mariage de vos parents ou s'ils ne sont pas mariés 1 copie intégrale de l'acte de reconnaissance prouvant votre filiation.

in my very loose translation that would be

- a photo
- an ID
- a proof of residence (utilities bill, rent contract, ...)
- full copy of your birth certificate with indication of your parentage
- full copy of both of your parents' birth certificates and all documents regarding the French nationality of your parents (ID card, passport, ...)
- fully copy of the marriage certificate of your parents or if unmarried a fully copy of proof of your descendance

Answer (score 2):

Since he lived in France, the passport isn't even needed (it would go some way towards establishing *possession d'état de Français* but that's only relevant for people living abroad for a long time). The main hurdle for you is establishing that he is your father. Specifically, you need a birth certificate and, if that's not enough to establish he is your father, something certifying that.

Then, you will need to gather a bunch of other documents and apply for a [*certificat de nationalité française*](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1051). Among the documents you need is your father's birth certificate but you can obtain that yourself from the relevant municipality, provided you can prove he is indeed your father.